# Transaction replication from testnet to mainnet

Tags: transactions, testnets, txpool

Gonna try to elaborate the situation:

- Say I have my address fully empty in both ropsten and mainnet, both with nonce equal to zero.
- Now I manage to get 1 ETH in both networks for that address.
- I send in ropsten that 1 ETH (minus fees) to another address.
- Say the corresponding transaction bytes that were previously broadcasted to the ropsten network are intercepted (or simply read from the mempool as a normal node).

Question is: **could an attacker replicate the exact same transaction in mainnet?** Bytes are already signed with the private key, and as far as I know there's no reference at all to the network ID the transaction is being broadcasted to, which makes me think that by simply broadcasting the transaction it could have an impact on mainnet.